# Синхронизация на уровне объекта

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Правильно ли я понимаю, если сделать синхронизированный метод (public synchronized void run()), то выполнение блокируется только на уровне объекта и это актуально только для синглтона. Т.е. если два потока создают инстансы этого обьекта, то они всервно смогут выполнить метод параллельно.

Comment: Да. Тут важно ограничение не на одновременное выполнение методов, а на одновременное  изменение данных. У каждого объекта есть свои данные.  Если два потока одновременно изменяют одни данные,  может получиться плохая ситуация. Если два потока изменяют разные данные(в разных объектах) - то ничего плохого не случиться.

Comment: Каких данных? Глобальных переменных объекта? Ну здесь опять же, актуально только для синглтона.

Comment: Почему актуально только для синглтона? Вы можете в одном объекте не-синглтоне работать с несколькими потоками.

Answer (score 1):

Да, выполнение будет заблокировано лишь на уровне экземпляра данного класа, поэтому если создать 2 разных экземпляра и дать их 2 разным потокам то они могут выполнять его независимо друг от друга